# Sweet Alert added # in URL how to prevent it?

Tags: jquery, sweetalert

[image: [![enter image description here][1]][1]]

```
 swal({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#62cb31",
                confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
                cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
                cancelButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                closeOnConfirm: false,
                closeOnCancel: true,                
            },
```

any one have idea how its prevent?

Comment: Please show us how you call this code, since im not sure it's swal who makes it.

Comment: Its show's click event

Comment: I'm not asking what it does, I'm asking to see more code. Like what triggers this code, the html element and so on

Comment: Hi Carsten Løvbo Andersen I debug its added by main.js library

Comment: I've tested the code and it works fine and does not create a # in the url. Without seeing more jquery / html code I can't help you